# Rds command line interface API on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cmd, rds

I want to run rds in command line mode but i am not able to run it as it is showing me 
the error !

CMD :

rds-describe-reserved-db-instances-offerings --db-instance-class db.m1.xlarge --duration 3 --marker true --product-description mysql

please help me , I am not able to understand the correct command ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a space between "rds" and "describe" instead of a dash.  So the whole command looks like this (I left out the "marker" - I'm not quite sure how that's meant to be used.)

Entire command:

```
aws rds describe-reserved-db-instances-offerings --db-instance-class db.m1.xlarge --duration 3 --product-description mysql
```

I'm using the cli version 1.2.12.

At this point, some valid options for --product-description seem to be:

```
mysql                             
oracle-ee
oracle-se
oracle-se1
postgres                    
sqlserver-ee
sqlserver-se
sqlserver-web
```

Comment: hi i not able to use some command can u guide me .... i the same command above i ma not able to take out the price of PostgreSQL
Oracle , SQL Server

Comment: If you leave off the "--product-description mysql" portion of the command you'll get every type of rds server available, including sql server, oracale and postgresql.

Comment: Also you can query with other specific values for --product-description.  I've updated my answer above to include the ones I was able to identify.

Comment: can we also check according to availability-zone